# Check if a position is clicked using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, position, mouselistener

I'm writing a simple program and want to know if an approximate position is clicked. I've got a hashmap with the position as key value and want to display a currently invisible object if the user clicks close enough to the position of the object - not just right at it. The position class just holds an x and a y value.

```
    HashMap<Position, Place> places = new HashMap<>(); //Assume this is populated

    @Override
    class WhatIsHere extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            Place place = places.get(new Position(me.getX(), me.getY()));
            if (place != null) {
                place.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nothing there");
            }
        }
    }
```

This bit of code finds the place if you click right on it though I don't know how to look for, say, me.getX()+-10 and find objects in that range.

Do I need to set four ints holding x-10 and x+10 etc. and just loop through all the positions inbetween? It seems awfully dumb to do it that way.

Comment: Have you considered a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)?

Answer (score 0):

I dislike exercises that require use of a particular collection, regardless of whether it is the best choice. One of the most important things to learn about the collections, and more generally about data structures, is picking which to use for a given job.

However, I understand you have to use HashMap. Here is one way to do it.

Divide the space up into small squares. Identify each square by e.g. the Point at the minimum x and minimum y. Create a HashMap that maps the square that are near at least one of your objects to the list of nearby objects.

To look up a point, calculate the Point identifying the square containing it. Look up that Point in the map. If it is not present, your point is not near any object. If it is present, check your point against each object in the list according to your nearness rules.

For some configurations of your objects, you may be able to ensure that each square is near at most one object. If so, you can replace the list with the object.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use *TreeMap* and you would be able to get a [sub map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-) which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Surely there's a smooth way to do it using a hashmap, isn't there? I've been given an assignment to do this operation using a hashmap, which is the reason I'm a bit stubborn about using it, please forgive me.